# Convert String to PFObject.. Parse

Tags: ios, swift, pointers, parse-platform

I am retrieving all the user details this way..

```
var userIds = [String]()
var userNames = [String]()
var profilePics = [PFFile]()
var gender = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var userQuery = PFUser.query()
        userQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

            if let objects = objects {

                self.userIds.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.userNames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.profilePics.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

                for object in objects {

                    if let user = object as? PFUser {
                        if user.objectId !=  PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId {

                            self.userIds.append(object.objectId as String!)
                            self.userNames.append(object["fullName"] as! String!)
                            self.profilePics.append(object["profilePicture"] as! PFFile!)
                            self.gender.append(object["gender"] as! String!)

                        }


                    }

                }


            }


            self.tableView.reloadData()

        })

}
```

now i have "follow" button in myCell.. saving this way..

```
 @IBAction func followButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    var followers:PFObject = PFObject(className: "Followers")
    followers["user"] = userIds[sender.tag] // Problem is here.. i want "user" column to be filled with userIds of users as Pointers not Strings. What should i do here??
    followers["follower"] = PFUser.currentUser()

    followers.saveInBackground()

}
```

Because i want to make relations with every object in "Followers" class that's why i want them to be in the form of Pointers.. Any suggestion please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a pointer to another PFObject (including PFUser) you will need to actually point to that object.

I see in your query that you are not adding any PFUsers to your array, but you are getting their object IDs.

Since a tag is only for an Int, you can not use it to pass a String (which a Parse objectID is).

You can subclass UIButton and create a new property to handle the objectID from parse and then use that to perform a query with the objectID and save the pointer to the result of that query. Or you can just add the object from your first query to your local array and use your button's tag to get the index of the object you want to point to.

Update

Since you have the objectId for the PFuser you want, you can get it and update your followers like so:

```
        let getOjbectByIdQuery = PFQuery(className: "User")
    getOjbectByIdQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: userIds[sender.tag])
    getOjbectByIdQuery.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock { (foundObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if let object = foundObject {

            var followers:PFObject = PFObject(className: "Followers")
            followers["user"] = object
            followers["follower"] = PFUser.currentUser()
            follwers.saveInBackground()

        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please type the whole code?? Beginner here.. and moreover userIds[sender.tag] is working fine but it is saving the userIds as String.

Comment: I've one more problem, if i tap on follow button on 0th position in the tableViewCell it automatically set unfollow title on last cell also :/ i don't know why. i guess something is happening on "tableView.reloadData()" can you help me here??

Comment: that sounds like a different problem, if you try to search and don't find an answer you should post a new question. I am glad your other problem is fixed though :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735945/not-able-to-reload-data-properly-when-retrieving-objects-from-parse 
here is the question