# Not able to reload data properly when retrieving objects from Parse

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I am retrieving data from "_User" class this way:

my declarations ..

```
 var userIds = [String]()
 var userNames = [String]()
 var profilePics = [PFFile]()
 var gender = [String]()


var userQuery = PFUser.query()
        userQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

            if let objects = objects {

                self.userIds.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.userNames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.profilePics.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

                for object in objects {

                    if let user = object as? PFUser {
                        if user.objectId != PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId {

                            self.userIds.append(object["objectId"] as! userListTableViewCell)  // getting an error here..  "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
                            self.userNames.append(object["fullName"] as! String!)
                            self.profilePics.append(object["profilePicture"] as! PFFile!)
                            self.gender.append(object["gender"] as! String!)

                        }


                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }


            }




        })
```

[image: screen shots of my app[![][1]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzAst.png)

here when i click on follow button for user "Rfdfbd" then automatically the "unfollow" title appears on user "Ihbj....." also :/ how can i fix this??

[image: Screen Shots of my app..]

my IBAction followButton code is here:

```
@IBAction func followButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    println(sender.tag)

    sender.setTitle("unfollow", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    let getOjbectByIdQuery = PFUser.query()
    getOjbectByIdQuery!.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: userIds[sender.tag])
    getOjbectByIdQuery!.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock { (foundObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if let object = foundObject {

            var followers:PFObject = PFObject(className: "Followers")
            followers["user"] = object
            followers["follower"] = PFUser.currentUser()
            followers.saveEventually()

        }
    }
}
```

I am using sender.tag for the follow button here..

Comment: This seems you have same button reference in different cells.That's why you update the button contents it effects all the places of button reference.

Comment: can you please elucidate your answer more??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem before and fixed it by embedding a button in each cell. Inside your `UITableView` you should try embedding each cell with a `UIButton`.

First make a custom `UITableViewCell` in a separate file. Then drag and make an `IBOutlet` for your `UIButton` inside your custom cell.

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var followButton: UIButton!
    var isFollowing:Bool = false
    //Declare other cell attributes here like picture, name, gender
    // ......
}
```

When you query and gather the data for your cells, you can store them in an array in your `UITableViewController`. For example, `var myCellArray = [MyCustomCell]()`. Then your `UITableViewController` will look something like this:

```
var myCellArray = [userListTableViewCell]()

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var userQuery = PFUser.query()
    userQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if let usersArray = objects as! [PFUser] {

            self.myCellArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

            for user in usersArray {

                if let user = object as? PFUser {
                    if user.objectId != PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId {
                        var myCell = userListTableViewCell()
                        myCell.userID = user.objectId
                        myCell.username = user["fullName"] as! String
                        myCell.gender = user["gender"] as! String

                        var userPicture = user["profilePicure"] as? PFFile
                        var image = UIImage(data:userPicture!.getData()!)
                        myCell.displayPicture.image = image

                        myCellArray.append(myCell)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    myCellArray.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier") as! userListTableViewCell

    //Edit the storyboard labels for each cell:
    cell.username.text = myCellArray[indexPath.row].username
    // etc....

    //Embed a button with each cell
    cell.followButton.layer.setValue(indexPath.row, forKey: "index")
    cell.followButton.addTarget(self, action: "followButtonTapped:", for ControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    if (myCellArray[indexPath.row].isFollowing == false){
        cell.followButton.setTitle("Follow", forState: .Normal)
    }else{
        cell.followButton.setTitle("Unfollow", forState: .Normal)
    }
    return cell
}

func followButtonTapped(sender: UIButton){
    let cellIndex : Int = (sender.layer.valueForKey("index")) as! Int
    //You now have the index of the cell whose play button was pressed so you can do something like
    if (myCellArray[cellIndex].isFollowing == false){
        myCellArray[cellIndex] = true
    }else{
        myCellArray[cellIndex] = false
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: can you elucidate "var myCellArray = [MyCustomCell]()" more??

Comment: You would create this inside your `UITableViewController` class before your functions. On `viewDidLoad` you should do your Parse `query` and loop through each `PFObject` in your Parse class. Inside the loop you can create a `MyCustomCell` and give it the properties from your Parse `query`. When you're done with your query, call `self.tableView.reloadData()` to load your cells.

Comment: i've made var userIds = [userListTableViewCell]() and i am getting error here.. 
    self.userIds.append(object.objectId as String!)  in my query and rest of the PFObjects by the other arrays i've explained.. like usernames, profilePics, gender..  :/
What am i doing wrong.??

Comment: Try using `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in })` function when you do your query. That way you are getting an `array` of your objects to loop through

Comment: Your edited query does not match the declaration I just gave you. You're not getting objects array from your query.

Comment: object.objectId isn't working .. says  cast from 'String?!' unrelated type 'userListTableViewCell' always fails. when i am using self.userIds.append(object.objectId as! userListTableViewCell)
I am sorry to bother you.. can you type the code ?? for my query..

Comment: see the edited question again.. i ve written the declarations also..
userListTableViewCell is myCustomCell

Comment: You still didn't correct your query. I have update my answer.

Comment: getting error where you have put myCell.userID = user.objectId .. "userListTableViewCell" does not have a member named 'userId'..

Comment: It wont have a member named `userId` until you create it in your `userListTableViewCell` class. Also note that I got rid all the arrays but one and put all that data into your custom cells.

Comment: should i declare it like an array? var userId = [String]() ? or what?

Comment: No, you don't need any arrays in your cell class with what you are doing right now. Simply create a variable in your cell class like so: `var userId: String?`

Comment: i've declared displayImage = UIImageView() . is it the right way?
how can images be shown on cells??

Comment: I would suggest you create a `UIImageView` on your cell in the storyboard, position how you want, and drag that over into your cell class. Then whatever name you give it you can assign the image to that.

Comment: you mean @IBOutlet?? like this ? @IBOutlet var dp: UIImageView! then use 'dp' instead of displayPicture??

Comment: Yeah just make sure it is connected to your `TableViewCell` on your storyboard

Comment: still getting an error "A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug." :(

Comment: That's just a Parse warning, not really an error. If you have any `save()` operations try to make the `saveInBackground()`. Like where you use `saveEventually()`

Comment: i haven't used saveEventually till now.. i am trying to retrieve data first.
i guess somethings there with "getData"

Comment: myCellArray[cellIndex] = true // error: cannot assign bool to a value of type 'userListTableViewCell'

Comment: Listen to what the error is telling you. `myCellArray[cellIndex]` returns a `userListTableViewCell`. You have to do `myCellArray[cellIndex].myVariable`  to get and change the properties of the cell

Comment: i did it like `myCellArray[cellIndex].isFollowing` . is that correct?? and i am still getting the warning.. :/

Comment: For the warning, check places you call Parse functions such as `findObjects....` or `save`  and make sure that that are all `inBackground` functions.

Comment: here i have one more problem that when i restart the app with the same user logged in, the user list table doesn't contain my already following users. :/ can you help me?

Comment: Check you Parse dashboard and make sure that you are saving the data.

Comment: I am saving the data :/

Comment: please dude help me out here.. i want to do it in home page of instagram type app. so i want o save the data that if the user is already following someone , then in that cell, "unfollow" button would appear.. please help, i m still stuck here.. @Kyle H

Comment: You'll have to do some debugging. Trace through your app where the query is done. Simply, you could run through the loop when doing your query and make sure all the data is being returned to the app. If the data is showing up in the Parse dashboard then you are just not corectly the data from the query correctly

Comment: Elucidate it .. sorry

Comment: I do not know how much further I can explain this......try putting `println` statements throughout your loops and print out the data so you can see for yourself whether it is correct or not. If you don't understand then I recommend reading through the Parse documentation section on queries.

Comment: Also, I don't know what your code looks like. Based on the above code you gave, I gave a proper solution. If you are still having the problem then you should adjust your code given to show all code involved with your problem. Until then I cannot do much more.