# UIButtons in tableViewCell, how to get already following users from Parse using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uibutton

I've been working on it from 2 weeks now, I've Instagram like app, where user can signUp and Login using Parse backend. Now after signUp a segue is made for the next screen called `userListTableViewController` here users will be allowed to follow the already existing users. Now i trying to retrieve data in `NSMutableArray` and show them as follows:

```
import UIKit

class userListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var data:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var isFollowing = [PFObject:Bool]()






func loadData() {

data.removeAllObjects()
isFollowing.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)


var userQuery = PFUser.query()
userQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

    if error != nil {

    } else {

        if let objects = objects {
             for object in objects {

                if let user = object as? PFObject {

                    if user.objectId != PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId {

                        self.data.addObject(user)




                        var followerQuery: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Followers")
                            followerQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
                            followerQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: user)

                        followerQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

                            if let objects = objects {

                                    if objects.count > 0 {

                                        self.isFollowing[user] = true


                            } else {

                                        self.isFollowing[user] = false


                                }

                            }

                                if self.isFollowing.count == self.data.count {

                                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                                }


                            })


                        }


                    }

                }

            }

        }

})

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

loadData()

}


/*
 var array:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: self.data.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects)
self.data = array as NSMutableArray

self.tableView.reloadData()

*/



 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
 super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

 }

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
// #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of sections.
return 1
}

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
// #warning Incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return data.count

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("users", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! userListTableViewCell

let userData:PFObject = self.data.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject


myCell.fullName.text = userData["objectId"] as! String!
myCell.genderLabel.text = userData["gender"] as! String!

   // var array:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: self.data.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects)
  //  self.data = array as NSMutableArray



let followedId = // What should i use here?? *****************

if isFollowing[followedId] == true { // ERROR!! not able to use followedId here.. how should i give a value so that it will check the particular user's objectId and isFollowing Bool value. ****************** 

    myCell.followButtton.setTitle("unfollow", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

} else {

    myCell.followButtton.setTitle("follow", forState: UIControlState.Normal)


}

userData["profilePicture"]?.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in

    if let downloadeImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

        myCell.dp.image = downloadeImage
    }

myCell.followButtton.tag = indexPath.row
myCell.followButtton.addTarget(self, action: "followButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    })



return myCell
}

 // IBActions..


func followButtonTapped(sender: UIButton){

   let userData:PFObject = self.data.objectAtIndex(sender.tag) as! PFObject

let followedId = userData["objectId"] as! PFObject

if isFollowing[followedId] == false {

    isFollowing[followedId] = true

    sender.setTitle("unfollow", forState: UIControlState.Normal)



    let getObjectByIdQuery = PFUser.query()
    getObjectByIdQuery?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: userData.objectId!)
    getObjectByIdQuery?.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({ (foundObject:PFObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if let object = foundObject {

            var followers:PFObject = PFObject(className: "Followers")
            followers["user"] = object
            followers["follower"] = PFUser.currentUser()

            followers.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    println(error)

                } else {

                    println("saved")

                }

            })


        }


    })


} else {

    isFollowing[followedId] = false
    sender.setTitle("follow", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Followers")
    query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    query.whereKey("user", equalTo: data[sender.tag])
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let objects = objects {

            for object in objects {

                object.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in

                    if error != nil {
                        println(error)

                    } else {

                        println("deleted")

                    }




                })

                }
                }


        })




    }
  }

}
```

shown the problem in the code as comment.. or else can you please suggest me some other way better than this.. i've tried to retrieve data in arrays also, there also i'm getting problem for the "follow" buttons. You can see the problem here.. [Not able to reload data properly when retrieving objects from Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735945/not-able-to-reload-data-properly-when-retrieving-objects-from-parse) .. Please check this link too..

Please help me out here.. Thanks..

Edit: I just want to make the user list with there gender full name and profile picture, and want to allow user to follow them with a button "follow" on each cell.. and if the app restarts, the users which have been already followed by the current user must be marked as "unfollow" to unfollow the user if current user wants it..

check the comments in the code.. error is there where you see "***************" it's in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of playing with PFUser, arrays and dictionaries, create a class `User` in application side.

```
class User: NSObject {

  var pfUser : PFObject?
  var isFollowing : Bool = false
}
```

And in `loadData` method,

```
func loadData() {

  // **************** Your Codes ********************

  if user.objectId != PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId {

        var otherUser = User()
        otherUser.pfUser = user

        // **************** Your Codes ********************

        followerQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

                       if let objects = objects {

                              if objects.count > 0 {

                                  otherUser.isFollowing = true
                              }
                       }
         })

       self.data.addObject(otherUser)
    }
}
```

Then use the single mutableArray `data` to populate `tableView`.

Comment: hey can you elucidate it more ? or maybe the full code would help me better.. <i am a beginner>