# How to Use Custom UIButton in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton, uitableview

I am trying to figure out the best way to apply UIButtons in tableViewCell, I've used `tag` method. like `cell.customButton.tag = indexPath.row`, then giving it a target. 
But it din't work fine for me if the tableViewCell has may things to show with the same button in all the cells.
There are two options to show the title of the button , just like if we follow a user and unfollow, so after deleting or clicking on any button , it changes the title of some other button also , So, `tag` method isn't a good option I guess.. Any help would be appreciated.. Thanks!

Comment: I read your question multiple times and I have no idea what you are asking. Do you have any code you can share?

Comment: Thanks for replying.. 
yes i have  . look at it.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735945/not-able-to-reload-data-properly-when-retrieving-objects-from-parse

Comment: Have you thought of adding a protocol to create a delegate for each cell?

Comment: can you give me a link to know about it?? @user1967709

Comment: @AkshayKheveria So your only problem is to bind `indexpath` with `button`?

Comment: exactly.. see i am getting this type of problem with `tag` 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735945/not-able-to-reload-data-properly-when-retrieving-objects-from-parse/31752971?noredirect=1#comment51696585_31752971      @iRealMe

Comment: Have you tried binding `userid` with the button `tag` instead of indexPath?

Comment: @iRealMe yup i've tried that only..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a protocol in a custom table view cell class is what i would suggest:

check out this [gitHub](http://www.github.com) [commit](https://github.com/LinnierGames/Overstack/tree/7cd925a1b0240f880a913ec16ded79958fe53bc2) or [download zip](https://github.com/LinnierGames/Overstack/archive/7cd925a1b0240f880a913ec16ded79958fe53bc2.zip) for the full project

### Adding a Subclass and protocol to a UITableViewCell

*I shall have this in the form of an answer later. let me know if you have any questions about the project*

Comment: Oh shoot :(  I keep doing that..well hopefully this helps someone else :)